# jQuery .attr("disabled", "disabled") not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, attr, jquery-attributes

Not sure why this isn't working.

When people click the 'edit' button of my application, the disabled textfields become editable:

```
$("#bewerken").click(function(e)    {
    $("input[disabled='disabled']").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

I then want to disable the textfields again when the user saves; I have this code bound to my save button:

```
$("#save_school_changes").click(function(e) {
    //stuff

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/school/save_changes",
        data: { //stuff },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#feedback_top").html("<p>" + data['message'] + "</p>").slideDown('slow').delay(2000).slideUp();
            $("input[type='text']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As far as I know, this should disable the textfields again. However, this does not seem to be working in Chrome. It does work in Firefox. I haven't had the chance to test in IE or Safari yet. Is there any way to make this work in Chrome aswell? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Side note: you can use the [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector instead of `input[disabled='disabled']`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you are using jQuery < 1.6
do this:

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.6+:

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", true);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)  for references why.

Or you can try this:

```
$('input:text').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

[see here for info on `:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

Comment: Using 1.5.2; sadly I still can't get it to work with the code you provided. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `$("input:text").attr("disabled", "disabled");`. Just pasting that in to check if I have the same code, heh. Can't get it to work. Jeez, stupid Chrome. :(

Comment: @Cabaret, can you post an example (working) code on jsfiddle.net and see if you get the same results?

Comment: Yeah so.. I don't get it. It works fine in JSfiddle and it doesn't work in my application. http://jsfiddle.net/b6L6g/1/

Comment: @cabaret, there must be a bug somehwere else

Comment: I switched some code around, not sure what it was that I did exactly but it works now. I'm using the last code example you provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I figured out what went wrong. When I set the attributes back to disabled, my browser doesn't automatically seem to update it. The fields only change to 'disabled' when I click on the page. This seems to be only in Chrome though. My code was right all the time, just a weird quirk in Chrome. Still going to use yours, it's far easier to read ;) Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @neal I am having problem with this $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')... the button is got disabled but the form is not submitting...its working in firefox but not working in chrome...I have tried all the ways you provided...Plz tell me is there any other way to solve this

Comment: @Sadaquat do you have a fiddle I can look at?

Answer (score 7):

For me, none of these answers worked, but I finally found one that did.

I needed this for IE-

```
$('input:text').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

I also had to add this for Chrome and Firefox -

```
$('input:text').AddClass("notactive");
```

and this -

```
<style type="text/css">
    .notactive {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 6):

if you are removing all disabled attributes from input, then why not just do:

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Then after ajax success:

```
$("input[type='text']").attr('disabled', true);
```

Make sure you use remove the disabled attribute before submit, or it won't submit that data.  If you need to submit it before changing, you need to use readonly instead.

Comment: One thing to note is to use readonly if you are looking to submit the data via get or post.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post but I none of this solution worked for me so I'm posting my solution if anyone find this helpful.

I just had the same problem.

In my case the control I needed to disable was a user control with child dropdowns which I could disable in IE but not in chrome.

my solution was to disable each child object, not just the usercontrol, with that code:

```
$('#controlName').find('*').each(function () { $(this).attr("disabled", true); })
```

It's working for me in chrome now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("input[type='text']").attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: This is an example of the technique: http://jsbin.com/ofuca3/edit  -- Is the input you're trying to disable being written in via ajax? Or does it already exist in the DOM?

Comment: It already exists in the DOM. I'll check out your link! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ??

Well prop() seems [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/XxBtq/).

Comment: Note to @cabaret tho, this is exclusive to jQuery 1.6, so if you arent on that version this wont work

Comment: see my answer and the OP's response

Answer (score 0):

Here:
http://jsbin.com/urize4/edit

Live Preview
http://jsbin.com/urize4/

You should use "`readonly`" instead like:

```
$("input[type='text']").attr("readonly", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks. i'll check it out. Is there a crucial difference between readonly and disabled or is it basically the same?

Comment: Its the same except for one minor thing... readonly doesnt have any default browser CSS whereas disabled does. In this example I just did `[readonly] { filter: alpha(opacity = 50); opacity:0.5; }` and achieved the same affect.

Comment: One big difference: fields with `readonly` set are sent to the server when the form is submitted, `disabled` elements are not.

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this was that the element using the disabled attr needed to be defined as a form element, .ie input type for it to work. Both worked with attr() and prop() but chose the latter for future maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly disabled attribute doesn't work with the anchor tags from HTML-5 onwards. Hence we have change it to ,let's say 'button' and style it accordingly with appropriate color,border-style etc. That's the most apt solution for any similar issue users are facing in Chrome . Only few elements support 'disabled' attribute:
Span , select, option, textarea, input , button.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the class

```
$("#...").addClass("disabled");
$("#...").removeClass("disabled");
```