# disabled attribute does not work in firefox - for a div

Tags: jquery, html

hi my dear friends :
the below code works perfect in ie9 , but does not work in firefox 3.6

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage -> is a div element

mean when we check this div with firebug , shows us disabled="disabled"
but i have a RadUpload Inside that div that is working still!

the html code is like below :

```
<div disabled="true" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage" class="RadUpload RadUpload_BlackByMe RadUpload_rtl RadUpload_BlackByMe_rtl" style="width: 325px;">
            <input autocomplete="off" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage_ClientState" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage_ClientState" type="hidden">
        <ul class="ruInputs" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImageListContainer"><li><span class="ruFileWrap ruStyled"><input style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -5000px;" class="ruFileInput" size="23" dir="ltr" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImagefile0" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImagefile0" type="file"><input size="22" class="ruFakeInput" type="text"><input class="ruButton ruBrowse" value="select" type="button"></span><input name="ClearInput" class="ruButton ruClear" value="erase" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImageclear0" type="button"></li></ul></div>
```

any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: What should a disabled div look like?

Comment: Have you tried 'true' instead of 'disabled'?

Comment: hello! $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage').attr('disabled', true); -> not work too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you are using jQuery < 1.6 do this:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.6+:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadUploadImage').prop("disabled", true);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for references why.

Same answer was given here: [jQuery .attr("disabled", "disabled") not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: dear @Neal thanks - i learned something new / but my radupload inside that div is still working - i test my code with prop! so confused1

Comment: whats do u mean `radupload inside that div`? what does ur html look like? can you add that to your question?

Comment: my Radupload source contains one ul -> disabled="disabled" about it does not work too ... also li's inside that ul!

Comment: @LostLord, lol you can't `disable` a div, only input elements like `input, select, textarea, etc` can be disabled

Comment: @LostLord no idea, i have never heard of a disabled div

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JQ for that , just use pure JS like that :

```
document.getElementById('x').disabled = true;
```

or if you wanna UNdisable it :

```
document.getElementById('x').disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed here too:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-image-button