# How to prevent double click in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

It is working perfect in chrome and ie,but when I tested it in firefox,it will not restrict double click on button.Button does not become disable immediately after first click.
My javascript Method :

```
function GRVMasterAddButton_Click(btn)
{
    if (Page_ClientValidate("masterGrp")) {
        document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
        __doPostBack(btn.id, '');
    }
}
```

Button declaration :

```
<asp:Button ID="frmSubmitInsert" runat="server" OnClick="frmSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="GRVMasterAddButton_Click(this)" Text="Add"
    Width="100px" Visible="false" ValidationGroup="masterGrp" />
```

Comment: It is solved! have to add 'return false;' Corrected : <asp:Button ID="frmSubmitInsert" runat="server" OnClick="frmSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="GRVMasterAddButton_Click(this);return false;" Text="Add"
                                                Width="100px" Visible="false" ValidationGroup="masterGrp" />          It also works in other browser.

Answer (score 0):

[disabled attribute does not work in firefox - for a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074529/disabled-attribute-does-not-work-in-firefox-for-a-div)

Look at this page... May you shuld change your Javascript code... About broswer problem :D

Comment: Nice :D May you can give yellow tick for my answer :P