# buttons show as disabled in console output, but can still be checked

Tags: jquery, css, forms, radio-button, slim

I'm using this for a function and it is showing up in my console as disabled, but I can still select the button. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Here is the line in the function (the rest of which is working):**

```
$("#paycd li#li_6hr input[name=radio6]:radio").attr('disabled',true);
```

**the slim (an html generator) code:**

```
li#li_48hr data-turnAroundTime="6"
      input.updateTurnaround id='updateTarget_6' type='radio' style='display:none' name="radio6"
```

**And my console output:**

```
<input class="updateTurnaround" id="updateTarget_6" name="radio6" style="display:none" type="radio" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: If you're using an **ID** for the `radio` button, why not just use `$("#updateTarget_6").prop('disabled',true);`?

Comment: Know what's funny?  Disabling an element with vanilla JavaScript is shorter:  `element.disabled = true`.

Comment: Please can you add a fiddle

Comment: Vucko, I tried that, but it didn't even show up in the console. Cinnamon, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Cinnamon, it didn't work in that form. Is this the syntax you would use? $('input#updateTarget_6').disabled = true; or $('input#updateTarget_6').element.disabled = true;

Comment: unfortunately, jsfiddle doesn't parse slim.

Comment: I don't use jQuery.  This is simple basic JavaScript.  *Element* just refers to the element in question (eg. `document.getElementById('foo').disabled = true`).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may have to do with attr() try using prop(). Please reference link below.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048113/1392355)

```
$('#updateTarget_6').prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$('#updateTarget_6')[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: Nope. Still can be checked but shows as disabled in the console.

Comment: @user2574616 Please create demo for a more accurate answer.

Comment: Turns out the radio button functionality is attached to the clicking of an image, so even though it appeared to be disabled, it could still be selected. I simply used ".unbind('click')" to disconnect from the click event.