# How to disable an element on the page with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $("#shikh_sec").attr("disabled", true); // doesn't work :/
    }
```

so , how to fix this and disable that element when clicking on the "img" tag

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Or just with a pure javascript:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    document.getElementById("shikh_sec").disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: Downvoter .. you could leave some comment prior to downvoting the answer .. I hate haters

Comment: I would guess that the DV'er wanted to use the default reason for down-voting. It doesn't indicate hate. Having said that, you're not using "pure JavaScript".

Comment: Probably the use of `$('img')` in something labeled as "pure javascript". If you're using jQuery, why not keep using jQuery in the following line?

Comment: you solved it , thanq

Comment: This is just an alternative, if it doesn't deserve upvote it doesn't deserve downvote either, after all it works!

Comment: Ok guys, read the question again please .. it's not about how to bind an event but how to disable some tag.

Comment: Yes @Goran.it, but it's not the best way when you are working with jQuery.

Comment: @Ragnar And using `attr` for modifying boolean attributes is not the best way when you are working with jQuery!

Comment: @undefined `attr("disabled", "disabled")` works for all jQuery versions.

Comment: @Ragnar Please check this question as an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `#shikh_sec` is an input that *can* be disabled (there's no such thing as a disabled `p` element, etc.), you want `prop()`:

```
$('#shikh_sec').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Note that this is limited to jQuery 1.6+

Comment: Hard to guess why not without knowing what the element *is*. Or if you might mean something different by 'disabled'. Or if the initial code is being run before the image in question has been added to the page. If you'd include sample code that actually shows the problem, we'd be better able to help.

Comment: For example, it works here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/qmFoJ  (having added the missing `)` that someone pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing a trailing ");"

A correct version would be something like this

```
$('#disable-me').click(function () {
$(this).attr("disabled", true); // doesn't work :/
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5v4mysgt/

Comment: The disabled attribute does not accept true as a value, you have to give it 'disabled' or use the prop setter if using jQuery 1.6+

Comment: It seems to be working for me, although it's proper to use $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled")

Answer (score 0):

Try using `disabled` instead of `true`:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $("#shikh_sec").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhfnzjuq/

```js
$(function(){
  $('img').click(function () {
    $("#shikh_sec").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/ws/200/amz/worldservice/live/assets/images/2014/09/23/140923115528_ultima_hora_640x360_bbc_nocredit.jpg">
    
<input id="shikh_sec" type="button" value="OK">
```