# jquery 1.8 disable / enable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm switching from jquery version 1.5.2  to 1.9 and my disable buttons arent working. They should enable after the form fields are populated and give the option to remove or save. This isnt working. I've tried in all browsers also. Here's the code.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a property:

```
$('#btnDel, #save').prop('disabled',true);
$('#btnDel, #save').prop('disabled',false);
```

Take a look at this SO answer to gain insight into the differences between attr and prop:

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: --`.prop()` needs a boolean value--

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead

Like :

```
$('#btnDel, #save').prop('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', false);
```