# Disabling a button based on an id clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I need a person who can help me solve this problem.The code below is working well with the post and the php code.

```
 //Getting the id of a buyer and loop through
    //sending a request to the seller
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.buyerRequest').click(function(){


    var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');

    $.post('SendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
        if(data=="true"){
            $(this).html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");

        }else if(data=="false"){
            alert('You have reached the maximum number you can send todays');
            }
        });

    });
    });
```

I have tested the php code,that is,if data returned is true output alert box and is working.For instance

```
if(data=="true"){
        alert(id);

}
```

However,on including this code

```
if(data=="true"){
        $(this).html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");

}
```

and clicking the current id,i am unable to disable it and change it's attributes to offer send.

How can i deal with this problem

This is my div code

```
echo"<li id='td_request'><a id='id_".$fetch_num['order_id']."' class='buyerRequest' href='#".$fetch_num['order_id']."'>Send Offer</a></li>";
```

Comment: on disabling... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/623952

Answer (score 0):

$(this) might not be a very good idea to use inside a $.post. You better use a reference to the html object.

for example
$("#mydiv").html('**Offer Send**').css('background','#dce6f1');

$(this) usually refers to the current object in the context, in this case the ajax request if i am not mistaken. For example...

```
$(".mydiv").each(function(){
//using $(this) here refers to the current instance of .mydiv; not the DOM or the body
});
```

So, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.buyerRequest').click(function(){


var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');

$.post('SendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
    if(data=="true"){
        $("#**yourdivid**").html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
        $("#**yourdivid**").attr("disabled","disabled");

    }else if(data=="false"){
        alert('You have reached the maximum number you can send todays');
        }
    });

});
});
```

Working Code

```
<a id='id_0' class='buyerRequest' href='#0'>Send Offer</a>
<div id='responseDIV'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buyerRequest').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');
        $.post('SendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
            if(data=="true"){
                $("#responseDIV").html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
                $("#id_0").removeAttr("href");

            }else if(data=="false"){
                alert('You have reached the maximum number you can send todays');
                }
            });

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: did you replace #yourdivid with your own div's id? did you give your div an ID in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "this" is ambiguous here, try to change into:

```
var currentBtn = $(this);
var id = currentBtn.attr('id').replace('id_','');

$.post('SendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
   if(data=="true"){
       currentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
       currentBtn.attr("disabled","disabled");

   }else if(data=="false"){
       alert('You have reached the maximum number you can send todays');
   }
});
```

if disabled attribute does not work, you can try:

```
currentBtn.prop("disabled", true);
```

It belongs to your jQuery's version , reference: [jQuery .attr("disabled", "disabled") not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome)

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks sir the send offer has worked however the attribute disabled is not working

Comment: You would try: currentBtn.prop("disabled",true);

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems.  I assume `this` is a button.  I created a div to apply the styling to.  The problem is that `this` is defined by scope.  Inside of the post callback, `this` refers to the actual post object, not an html element.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.buyerRequest').click(function() {  

      var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_',''); 

      $.post('SendingOffer.php', {"id":id}, function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         if (data.length>0) {
            $('#my_div').html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
            $('#id_my_button').prop("disabled",true);
         }
         else {
            alert('You have reached the maximum number you can send todays');
         }
      }); 
   });
});

</script>

<input type='button' class='buyerRequest' id='id_my_button' value='my_button'> 
<br/>
<div id='my_div'></div>
```