# disable upload page after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have button(in future many), and form. What i want, that after submit of the page that call form became not available.

[image]

But after submit page is upload. How to avoid this?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function()   {

              var btn =  $('#btn1');
              var form = $('#myform');
              var formbtn =   $('#submit');

               btn.on ('mouseup', function(){
                     form.toggle(200);


           });

           formbtn.on('mouseup', function(){
              btn.html('bought!');
               btn.attr('disable', true);
              return false;
           });


        });


 <div id = "myform">

        <form id = "my">
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>


  <button id="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

    </div>
```

And how in future  choice button to disable from  the plurality of buttons, it will be some array?

Comment: Do you want the "BUY" button to hide after you submit form?

Comment: hide, or not active with html "
bought",  does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you will want to change

```
btn.attr('disable', true);
```

to

```
btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

For the second part of your question, if I understand correctly, you could use a class or element selector for multiple buttons

```
$('button')
$('.buttonClass')
```

To add, depending on the version of jQuery, you may want to use .prop instead of .attr for 1.6+.

See this answer for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048113/1927071