# interaction between html checkboxes via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that has a lot of columns, but the first two columns are 'Yes' and 'No' columns. By default the 'Yes' column is checked and 'No' column is unchecked. What I want is, If I uncheck the 'Yes' column then the 'No' column will get checked and all the other columns will be disabled. If I again click/check the 'Yes' column then the 'No' column will get unchecked and all the other columns will be enabled again.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is when the second time I click on the 'Yes' box, it should be back to 'checked' again but it isn't. Here is a sample of [**`My Code`**](https://jsfiddle.net/1rhrco48/3/).

```js
$('tr td input[type="checkbox"].yes').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(.yes, .no)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  $(this).closest('tr').find(":input(.no)").prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Yes</th>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>textinput</th>
    <th>Select 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="no" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1111" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="AAAAA" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="no" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="2222" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="BBBB" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="no" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="3333" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="CCCC" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: include your code in the OP

Comment: Please add your code into the question.

Comment: You can use one checkbox instead of two. See https://jsfiddle.net/1rhrco48/5/

Comment: if you only required functionality you can use radio box, is check box important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see Two problems with your code.

1. `...find(":input(.no)")...` should be just `...find(":input.no")...`
2. `.attr()` **[is buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048113/3639582)** with `disabled="true"` v/s `disabled="disabled"`, use `.prop()` in cases to truth value checks.

---

```
$('tr td input[type="checkbox"].yes').change( function() {
   $parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
   $parentTr.find(":input:not(.yes, .no)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   $parentTr.find(":input.no").prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rhrco48/4/)**

```js
$('tr td input[type="checkbox"].yes').change( function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(.yes, .no)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input.no").prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

table, th, td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Yes</th>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>textinput</th>
    <th>Select 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input class="no" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1111"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="AAAAA"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input class="no" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2222"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="BBBB"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input class="no" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3333"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="CCCC"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, a more better way of handling clicks on `no` - **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rhrco48/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just change your javascript to:

```
$('tr td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(.yes, .no)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input(.no)").prop('checked', !this.checked);
   $(this).prop('checked',!$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Check working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4d5k0ams/