# How enable or disable inputs uses jQuery based on the value of a select option?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a select and two `inputs`. I want when I choose `2nd` choice from the select element for the `two` inputs will be deactivated.

My code is below but the inputs are not being disabled, how do I get it to work?

```js
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
  var stateID = $(this).val();
  if (stateID != 2) {
    $("divb").attr("disabled", true);
    $("divn").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="1">choose1</option>
      <option value="2">choose2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divb">
    <label>business <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="entreprise" id="entreprise" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divn">
    <label>name Piece <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="piece" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. You **can** use `attr` OR `prop` either one. The only thing you were doing wrong was you are `disabling` the actual `divs` but not the `input` itself. The disable property work only on `inputs` not the div `elements`

To disable the actual `inputs` we can jQuery [decendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) - Also, in your current jQuery `code` your are missing `#` selector sign as well.

**Edit:** Added `prop` method but you can use `attr` as well if you are **only** disabling the inputs

Here is an example of **decendant selector**

```
$("#divb > input").prop("disabled", true);
$("#divn > input").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Live Working Code:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
  var stateID = $(this).val();
  if (stateID == '2') {
    $("#divb > input").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#divn > input").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#divb > input").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#divn > input").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="1">choose1</option>
      <option value="2">choose2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divb">
    <label>business <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="entreprise" id="entreprise" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divn">
    <label>name Piece <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="piece" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery code:

```js
$('#divb').prop('disabled', true);
$('#divn').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: to remove the `disabled` attribute, you could use `.removeAttr('disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons that your jQuery is not disabling the inputs:

**1. You need to use `prop()`** and not `attr()` (which did work, but since jQuery v1.6 `prop` is the recommended method over `attr` for properties)

```
$(element).prop("disabled", true);
```

**2. You are not using the selector correctly** to select the element to disable:

- you need to select the *input*. You're selecting the `divb` element which is the form-group
- To select using an id you need to use `#` e.g. `#divb` or for a class you use `.` e.g. `.form-control`

**To disable *all* inputs:** `input.form-control` will select all of them so we can change them all together:

```
$("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Full function code:**

```
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
  var stateID = $(this).val();

  // disable all inputs when option 2 is selected, enable them otherwise
  if (stateID == 2) 
    $("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
  else
    $("input.form-control").prop("disabled", false);

});
```

**To select the the inputs individually:**

```
// using the id of the input itself
$("#entreprise").prop("disabled", true);

// this input has no id or class, so we can use name (but an id or class would be better)
$("input[name='piece']").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
  var stateID = $(this).val();

  if (stateID == 2) 
    $("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
  else
    $("input.form-control").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="1">choose1</option>
      <option value="2">choose2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divb">
    <label>business <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="entreprise" id="entreprise" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divn">
    <label>name Piece <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="piece" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```