# How to disabled field with if-else condition in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a problem on disabled input field on certain condition. In this case, user can add multiple row in a form. But, the number of row is greater than four, then some of the field will be disabled. Here my segment of JavaScript. In order to know the number of row already exceed or not, I check using index number.

But the problem is, the code seems like didn't check the `if-else` condition.

```
var valIndex =0;
    for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
        valIndex = i+1;

        $(forms.get(i)).find('.assign_label_number').text(" - " + valIndex +  nth(valIndex));
        console.log(valIndex);
        
        document.getElementById("gift").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var gift = $(forms.get(i)).find('input[id^=id_Phone1][id$=less_tax_examption]');
            if(valIndex => 4){
                console.log('disabled')
                gift.prop("disabled", true);
            }
            
            else{
                console.log('enable')
                gift.prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
});
```

Here the HtML code segment:

```
<div id="giftoftelpagerpda-dynamic">
{{ phoneformset.management_form }}
{% for phone in phoneformset %}
<div class="phone1form-row mb-4">

<div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label class="">Gift of Telephone/ Mobile Phone/ Pager and PDA</label>
        <label><span class="assign_label_number" id="id_Phone1-0-label_number"></span></label>
    </div>
    {% if phoneformset.can_delete %}
        {{ phone.DELETE | add_class:"invisible"}}
    {% endif %}
    <button id="gift" style="" class="btn btn-success btn-dynamic-xs add-form-row phone1formbutton" type="button"> <span class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
    {{ phone.apb_fields.as_hidden }}
    {{ phone.description.as_hidden }} 
    {{ phone.apbid.as_hidden }}
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
        <div>
            {{ phone.value_before_tax }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <label class="">Less: Tax Exemption</label>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-2">
        {{ phone.less_tax_examption }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="tarfnl2 col col-lg-2">
        {{ phone.apb_value | attr:"readonly:readonly" }}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Actually it work just fine if I remove the `document.getElementById`. But since there is few field with different condition, so I need to differentiate each of the button by `Id`.

I already tried to used `.attr("disabled", true)` also didn't work

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you in advanced for your help and time.

Comment: Would you make a jsfiddle or codepen with your code? It can be useful to see the html

Comment: please add relevant html to understand the problem statement correctly

Comment: Do your element have an ID that contains both `id_Phone1` and `less_tax_examption` ?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i already add the relevent html code segment

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @AlePlo Im not sure is it possible or not since im using crispy.

Comment: @jat `find('input[id^=id_Phone1][id$=less_tax_examption]')` is looking for an element that looks like this `<input id="id_Phone1Somethingless_tax_examption" />` and you dont have that

Comment: @natel i already tried the solution on that page as well but didn't work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen actually i have that element in form.py file. less_tax_examption=forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(
  attrs= {
  "class":"converamt textinput textInput form-control commanumber class_less_tax_examption",
  }))

Comment: @jat `class_less_tax_examption` is your class not id you write `[id$=less_tax_examption]`